# Logic problem: Truth value of statement the product of $x^2$ and $x^3$ is $x^6$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I want to understand why these statements below are false. I assumed that the statements are true because they are real numbers

- The product of $x^2$ and $x^3$ is $x^6$
- The $x^2>0$ for any real number $x$

Comment: Without any quantifier, the first one is not even a statement, since it depends on $x$ (it doesn't matter that it's true for each real $x$), hence is neither true nor false. The second one is just false because it fails for $x=0$.

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris ...can we pretend I never said that? :P

Comment: Was $x^6$ a typo for $x^5$?

Comment: @Wojowu:  Sure thing!  =)

Comment: @bof probably not, as OP is trying to figure out why the given statements are _false_.

Comment: FWIW, the first statement is true if $x = 0$ or $x=1$, and *false* otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - The product of $x^2$ and $x^3$ is $x^6$

Do you know a rule for $\boxed{x^m x^n = \ldots}$ ?

Don't confuse it with the rule for $\boxed{\left(x^m\right)^n = \ldots}$ !

If not, look them up.

> - The $x^2>0$ for any real number $x$

But also $0$ is a real number, so...

Comment: FWIW, the first statement is true if $x = 0$ or $x=1$, and *false* otherwise.

Comment: It's hard to tell if OP copied the problem literally or not; I'm trying to answer in the spirit of what I assume to be the underlying idea of the question. Of course the question would benefit from a more precise phrasing.